# How to plot the scatter plot of the following simulation in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have the following code to get `result`

```
result=zeros(1,100)
i=0
for x=0:0.5:50
    i=i+1
    mat=[-12,4,4;4,6,-x-10;-8,-1,-x]
    con=[-120;0;-240]
    X = linsolve( mat,con)
    result(1,i)=X(3,1)
end
```

I try to plot the `x=0:0.5:19` and its corresponding `result` `y=result(1：39)`

```
xlabel('resistance'), ylabel(' through the fuse')     % Set the label on the corresponding axis

y=result(1：39)
x=0:0.5:19
plot(x, y)             % plot the values of x and y as a line plot
scatter(x, y)          % plot the values of x and y in a scatter plot
xline(x), yline(y)     % draw a vertical / horizontal line at the specified value
```

But it shows the error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this line:

```
y=result(1：39)
```

you have a forgeign letter `：` this is not the ASCII character `:`, it's a Unicode character `U+FF1A` that is causing an issue, simply replace it and things will work.

```
y=result(1:39)
```